# Oauth2.0 redirection attack

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

The Oauth2.0 protocol says the following:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.6

```
     When the attacker's user-agent is sent to the authorization server to grant access, 
the attacker grabs the  authorization URI provided by the legitimate client and replaces 
the client's redirection URI with a URI under the control of the attacker.  The attacker 
then tricks the victim into following the  manipulated link to authorize access to the 
legitimate client.
```

How can an attacker trick/redirect the victim to a manipulated link? How easy is that to do? Can someone give me an example of this attack?

Answer (score 0):

I'd read the next paragraph:

> The victim is then redirected to an    endpoint under the control of
>   the attacker with the authorization code.  The attacker completes
>   the authorization flow by sending the    authorization code to the
>   client using the original redirection URI    provided by the client. 
>   The client exchanges the authorization code    with an access token
>   and links it to the attacker's client account,    which can now gain
>   access to the protected resources authorized by    the victim (via the
>   client).

how it works? the attacker owns his website, www.attacker.com. after grabbing the authorization URI, the attacker replaces the "redirect_uri" param and places there his own URL, "www.attacker.com". then, the oauth-server redirects back to this URL, with the auth code as a param (this is the response). this way the attacker gets the code, and then easily he exchanges it with an access token, and bang! he has access to the "resource server" on behalf of the poor victim.